# How to use isParallel and shorten methods in a segments class?

Tags: java

I have a segment class with includes a bunch of codes. I have stuck on using two methods, isParallel and shorten methods. Here is my code so far(I have a point class as well which linked to this class):

```js
  public class Segment {

 //two Points that hold endpoints of the segment
 private Point p1, p2;
 
 
 //Default constructor that will set the endpoints to new
 //Points with values (0,0) and (4,4)
 public Segment(){
  this(0, 0, 4, 4);
 }
 
 //Parameterized constructor that accepts (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
 //and creates and sets the endpoints
 public Segment(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2){
  this.p1 = new Point(x1, y1);
  this.p2 = new Point(x2, y2);
 }
 
 //Parameterized constructor that accepts (Point p1, Point p2) and sets both
 //the endpoints to a deep copy of the Points that are passed in.
 public Segment( Point p1, Point p2){
  this.p1 = new Point(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
  this.p2 = new Point(p2.getX(), p2.getY());
 }
 
 //Copy constructor that accepts a Segment and initializes the data (of the
 //new Segment being created) to be the same as the Segment that was received.
 public Segment(Segment other){
  p1 = other.getP1();
  p2 = other.getP2();
 }

 public Point getP1(){
  return p1;
 }
 
 public Point getP2(){
  return p2;
 }
 
 //The length method returns the length of the Segment.In fact, this method is same as distanceTo method
 //So we can use distanceTo method which is already defined in Point class
 public double length(){
  return (p1.distanceTo(p2));
 }
 
 //The translate method returns nothing and should translate, or shift, 
 //itself (the Segment) by the distances passed in
 public void translate(int xmove, int ymove) {
         p1.translate(xmove,ymove);
         p2.translate(xmove,ymove);
  }
 
 //The midpoint method calculates and returns the midpoint of the Segment as a new Point
 public Point midpoint(){
  return (p1.halfWayTo(p2)); 
 }
 
 //The slope method returns the slope of the Segment as a double.
 public double slope(){
   return (double)(p2.getY() - p1.getY()) / (p1.getX() - p2.getX());
 }


 /**
  * The isParallel method returns true/false depending on whether the current Segment
  * is parallel to the Segment received.   Think about how you can tell if two segments
  * are parallel.  Note: Two overlapping segments ARE parallel.
  */
  public boolean isParallel( Segment s1 ){

  
{
    
  /**
  * The shorten method changes its (the Segment's) endpoints so that they are both halfway
  * to the midpoint. Example: The segment (0,0)---(12,16) has midpoint (6,8).  After
  * calling the shorten method, the segment should be (3,4)---(9,12).  Each endpoint
  * has moved in toward the midpoint (which stayed the same).  So (3,4) is halfway between
  * (0,0) and (6,8) and (9,12) is halfway between (12,16) and (6,8).
  */
    public void shorten();
```

Can someone give me an idea of how to use these two methods in my code. I really appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Comment: My hunch is that you're not asking what you wish to ask. Do you want to implement `isParallel` and `shorten`?

Comment: I just need to know how to write those methods! Or maybe yes! I want to know how to implement them!

Comment: Indeed, a rewrite of your question is due! As for the matter at hand, all you need is a bit of mathematical support to your algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am actually working on the same exact assignment! For the `isParallel` method, you need to check and see if the current Segment's slope is the same as the slope of the Segment received. I haven't worked on the shorten method so I can't help you with that yet.

Also, in my class (since I'm doing the same assignment), we aren't suppose to use the `getX()` and `getY()` methods since they defeat the whole purpose of learning about encapsulation. We need to actually ask the Point class to calculate the information for the points. For example, with the slope method instead of returning `return (double)(p2.getY() - p1.getY()) / (p1.getX() - p2.getX());`, I made a method inside of Point to calculate the slope of two points called `calcSlope`. And to call that method within the `Slope` method inside Segment: `return p1.calcSlope(p2);`.

Hopefully that helps!